# Starting a Gearman worker from Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, gearman

I have been working on a php mvc web application using codeigniter and need to process some long running tasks.

I checked through several options (RabbitMQ, Gearman, IronMQ etc) and decided to use Gearman of it's simplecity. I went through the samples and tutorials in gearman.org which shows how to start a `GearmanWorker` using worker.php.

my concern is, in mvc architecture where does this `GearmanWorker` is initiated and started?

1. Does it started through a controller method OR
2. Do we need to initiate the `GearmanWorker` from cli(console)? If it's started from cli then how to handle if the already started worker has stopped for some reason when we make a `GearmanClient->do('some task')`

a  [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604135/start-and-stopping-workers-in-gearman-php) but not clear enough for me

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend to start worker from the controller. You can start several workers distributed over network and using `workers` [text command](http://gearman.org/protocol/) for monitoring purpose. `gearmand` dispatch a job to the next idle worker.

Maybe [SUBMIT_JOB_BG](http://gearman.org/protocol/) is a good option for you to avoid web server timeout, if job execution takes long.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like this presentation https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/giberti/gearman-and-codeigniter will give some clear idea.

Comment: Nice presentation. Thanks for sharing. But take into account it is a little bit outdated. I would advice you to use newest release from [github](https://github.com/gearman/gearmand)